# antd 5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd/dist/antd.less'

Tags: reactjs, antd

I've updated antd to 5.0.0. I've these imports which are giving error now.

```
@import '~antd/es/style/themes/default.less';
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
```

what should I replace with in new versions?

Comment: I do have the same issue.  @import 'antd/dist/antd.compact.less'; is not found anymore

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I need the variables as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From v4 to v5, antd CSS files are no longer included in package.

Since CSS-in-JS supports importing on demand, the original `antd/dist/antd.css` has also been abandoned.

If you need to reset some basic styles, please use `import antd/dist/reset.css`. So just delete this code if you don't need to reset basic styles.

Reference: https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5

Comment: I was using antd less variables in my project's less files. Getting `Cannot resolve variable`. I cannot find any less files in antd dist now. How do I correctly import the variables?

Comment: Ok, I understand after visiting the link. v5 says no to less and css files.

Comment: Is there any way to get a dump of the antd v5 css?  I want to generate static html for an "export to html" feature, and I need a static dump of the css.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of those imports, import this in `App.js`

`import 'antd/dist/reset.css';`

Comment: I'm using only less files in my project and I'm using less variables from antd's less in my project's less files. Now for the antd less variables used in my project's less files, I'm getting error `Cannot resolve variable`

Comment: Check the [Change log](https://ant.design/changelog). They remove **Remove less and css in package** and Check the [installation guide](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) after `yarn add antd`, they made a few changes in `v5.x.x`